# Angular Material Selection List - String to Observable

Tags: angular

I am using this example :
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-selection-list-demo1?file=app%2Flist-selection-example.ts

but instead of typesOfShoes being of type string, I wanted to use it as an Observable of an interface Events I created.

When making this type of change, it gives an error in this part of the code:

> this.typesOfShoes.length

> Error: 'Property 'length' does not exist on type 'Observable<Events[]>'

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Please show your version of the code to debug, the example works fine.

Comment: You have to subscribe to your observable and make your instructions inside it.